# Pandas Q-Cut by Row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named "df" with a datetime index and four columns:

```
            A    B   C   D
1/1/2020    0.1 0.3 0.2 0.2
1/2/2020    0.3 0.1 0.3 0.3
1/3/2020    0.2 0.2 0.3 0.1
1/4/2020    0.1 0.1 0.1 0.3
```

I would like to divide the data into 4 "discretized" quantiles.

If I wanted to do this for the column "A", all I would need to do is to use Pandas's q-cut function as below:

```
df["A"] = pd.qcut(df["A"], 4)
```

However, the problem is I would like to create quantiles for each date, i.e. to divide the data into 4 quintiles for each row (NOT column). How would I do this?

Comment: do u mind sharing a dataframe of ur expected output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` parameter:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 4, duplicates='drop'), axis=1)
```